# find available port to run server

Tags: python, server

What's the best approach in python to do something like what happens when you run `jupyter notebook`, in other words, run a server (for example, with `http.server`) on some available port if the default one isn't available? Is it common to just catch the error if starting the server fails and try a different port until it works?

Answer (score 1):

You can use port 0 - this will bind your server to some port that is currently known to be available by kernel. However, that makes a problem of service discovery - how your clients will know which port number server is listening on? If that's only you, shouldn't be big deal.

Comment: and as a developer of the application, how do I find out the port it ended up using?

Comment: You can get current port number used by socket `s` using `s.getsockname()[1]`. You will need to use some http.server methods to get socket.